# akka-testkit without ScalaTest

Tags: scalatest, akka-testkit

I want to use utest with akka-testkit.
How can I disable ScalaTest in akka-testkit?

Running the test an empty ScalaTest is executed every time.

```
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 957 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[info] utest
[info] Tests: 1, Passed: 1, Failed: 0
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unregistering ScalaTest by filtering it out of [`testFrameworks`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/f0b54ca3a0a4b8b1df9ce5a73724df83f638d40f/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala#L276) setting in `build.sbt` like so

```
testFrameworks := {
  testFrameworks.value.filterNot(_.toString.contains("scalatest"))
}
```

Now `show testFrameworks` gives

```
show testFrameworks
[info] * TestFramework(org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework)
[info] * TestFramework(org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework, org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework)
[info] * TestFramework(org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework)
[info] * TestFramework(com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework)
[info] * TestFramework(utest.runner.Framework)
```

where we see `TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)` is not present.